# XML SelectSingleNode Namespacing issue

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to get a single value from an XML using the SelectSingleNode, but it keeps returning null on me.

I've been looking here on SO and it seems it has something to do with the namespace. I tried adding it but I keep getting null.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xnl="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xnl:4" 
     xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xal:4" 
     xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml" 
     xmlns:martine="http://www.martine.be/extensions"
     Id="510" 
     SchemaVersion="7.0" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml schema/510-count-v7-0.xsd
            http://www.martine.be/extensions schema/martine-eml-extensions.xsd">


    <EMLHeader>
        <TransactionId>01</TransactionId>
        <ManagingAuthority>                                                         
            <AuthorityIdentifier>2</AuthorityIdentifier>
            <AuthorityName>
                <NameElement ElementType="">VLR</NameElement>
            </AuthorityName>            
            <Description>Some Description</Description>
            <OrganizationURL>Unknown</OrganizationURL>
            <AuthorityAddress/>     
        </ManagingAuthority>
    </EMLHeader>
```

I'm trying to extract the Description using the code below:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            
doc.LoadXml(content);

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml");

XmlNode testNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:EML/ns:EMLHeader/ns:ManagingAuthority/ns:Description", nsmgr);
if (testNode != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(testNode.InnerText);
}
```

What am doing wrong?

Comment: It worked for me : https://dotnetfiddle.net/sZVzaX

Comment: Wow,I tried your fiddle and it was working indeed... So I went back to look in my code and I discovered that there was a space in my namespace that wasn't supposed to be there. Now it's working!

Comment: Weird. How come that space is not there in what you posted above?

Comment: Because when I was copying the code in the window here, for some reason it put in additional spaces everywhere, so I saw that the formatting here in the textfield was wrong, so I modified it here and unknowingly solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this and you are missing closing `</EML>` tag. This was the error I got

**Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: EML. Line 24, position 17.**

### TestCodeApp.cs

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            
        doc.Load("input.xml");

        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml");

        XmlNode testNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:EML/ns:EMLHeader/ns:ManagingAuthority/ns:Description", nsmgr);
        if (testNode != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testNode.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

### input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xnl="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xnl:4" 
     xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xal:4" 
     xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml" 
     xmlns:martine="http://www.martine.be/extensions"
     Id="510" 
     SchemaVersion="7.0" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml schema/510-count-v7-0.xsd
            http://www.martine.be/extensions schema/martine-eml-extensions.xsd">


    <EMLHeader>
        <TransactionId>01</TransactionId>
        <ManagingAuthority>                                                         
            <AuthorityIdentifier>2</AuthorityIdentifier>
            <AuthorityName>
                <NameElement ElementType="">VLR</NameElement>
            </AuthorityName>            
            <Description>Some Description</Description>
            <OrganizationURL>Unknown</OrganizationURL>
            <AuthorityAddress/>     
        </ManagingAuthority>
    </EMLHeader>
</EML>
```

Comment: You are correct Hassan, but I copied the above segment from a much larger XML-file so I did not copy the endtag along which was at the bottom of my XML-file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code look OK, except:

1. you missed close node in the xml file: **""**
2. if your content is contain information of above xml, then you can use       **doc.LoadXML(content)**, otherwise you should use **doc.Load(fileName).**

Your xml file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xnl="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xnl:4"
     xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xal:4"
     xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml"
     xmlns:martine="http://www.martine.be/extensions"
     Id="510"
     SchemaVersion="7.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml schema/510-count-v7-0.xsd
            http://www.martine.be/extensions schema/martine-eml-extensions.xsd">


  <EMLHeader>
    <TransactionId>01</TransactionId>
    <ManagingAuthority>
      <AuthorityIdentifier>2</AuthorityIdentifier>
      <AuthorityName>
        <NameElement ElementType="">VLR</NameElement>
      </AuthorityName>
      <Description>Some Description</Description>
      <OrganizationURL>Unknown</OrganizationURL>
      <AuthorityAddress/>
    </ManagingAuthority>
  </EMLHeader>
</EML>
```

And then you can read it:

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(fileName);

            var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:oasis:names:tc:evs:schema:eml");

            XmlNode testNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:EML/ns:EMLHeader/ns:ManagingAuthority/ns:Description", nsmgr);
            if (testNode != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(testNode.InnerText);
            }
```